# What is the best material to use in a solar heater box to convert solar energy into heat energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

Suppose you want to design a solar heater box with the dimensions: 1 sq meter x 30.48 cm H.
5 sides of the box's interior will be insulated and the interior will be totally black. Ideal glass will be placed on top of the box.  An inlet hole/s & outlet hole/s will be made in the box to optimize heated air flow out of the box.

Sunlight will travel though the glass, into the box & be converted into heat and then be blown by a fan into the space that you want to heat.

Your goal is to design the interior of the box to optimally convert the solar energy into heat energy at the highest rate.  Which material/s would you use?  A black insulator liner at the bottom of the box only?  Or, a black aluminum sheet bent to create optimal surface area? Or, something else? 
Note:  Assume the box tracks the sun for optimal solar energy exposure over the given box area & no additional mirrors or other mechanisms are used to concentrate or otherwise increase the amount of solar energy that enters the box.

Comment: It pretty much doesn't matter what you do since the box will, at most, generate about 200W of heat even under best conditions, which is way too little to heat even a small sized room. As far as optimization is concerned, energy capturing devices don't have to be optimized for efficiency but for cost and, in case of something like this, for a sufficient lifetime under pretty tough environmental conditions. Roofing materials like corrugated steel and roofing panels cut to size and then assembled with a few rivets will do just fine, plus a heat resistant black paint.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question.  I'm curious, how did you arrive at the conclusion that the most heat that will be generated is 200W?  According to NREL data, the lowest solar radiation for my latitude would be 3.67 kWh/m^2/day?  Also, I tested the temp of 3 materials (black painted aluminum (102.6°F), black rubber (121.8°F), & black thermal plastic (130.1°F) in direct sunlight using a laser temp measurement device. As expected, due to different thermal mass & conductivity, the temps were quite different. Interestingly though, the rubber felt the warmest to touch.

Comment: I was starting with  0.3m^2 collecting area. Given that the solar constant is around 1kW/m^2, the max. heat flow would be around 300W and if you factor a reasonable efficiency in you end up around 200W, which is just too little to make an appreciable difference for heating even a small sized room. I think you will have to go ten times the size if you really want to make a difference, but even that is a fairly small collector. I would stay away from plastic and rubber, these materials are probably not safe. Go with metal and heat resistant paint.

Comment: Why did you start with .3m^2?  My example specified 1 sq meter.  Also, why did you 'factor' in what you call "a reasonable efficiency" of 2/3 into your rationale?  The essence of my question is about the heat conducting materials--specifically which (if any) is best & why & how to determine that mathematically.  I've read that metals are supposed to be best, and I can calculate:  thermal calories = mass of material * specific heat of material * temp diff, but I'm not confident that that equation would be all that is needed to arrive at a sound conclusion.

Comment: My mistake! In that case you can probably get 700W out of it, or so, with full sun at the right angle and if it's well insulated. Then you are only short by a factor of three, not a factor of ten. The efficiency is just pulled out of my ear, if you don't mind. Nothing in life is 100% efficient, not even a black box and oversizing a little is much better than undersizing a lot. You don't need much of a heat conduction, since you are directly heating the air around the material. What you need is sufficient air-flow, a larger fan will be better. Don't waste time on math, it won't help much.

Comment: @CuriousOne - I intentionally chose a 1 sq meter box so that later scaling would be easier.  What does this mean "Then you are only short by a factor of three..."  3 times what?  The heat needed depends on the desired internal temp, the ouside temp, the insulation, & the heat gain channeled by the system.  For example:  Such a system in MN during the deep cold of winter would be virtually useless as they need 50 btu/sq (depending on outside temp, room vol, insulation, wind, etc)--however a sys in a Southern city wouldn't need to produce too many BTUs as the outside temp is significantly warmer

Comment: I was merely trying to say that you need at least 3m^2 of collection area to get something useful out of such a system even under best circumstances and, honestly, I wouldn't want to rely much on it under less than near ideal circumstances (like MN). Since you are aware of that, it seems, the comment was superfluous. Did you, by the way, survey the product space for cheap products from China? No need to reinvent the wheel when you can buy cheap wheels from over there.

Comment: @CuriousOne - You really haven't directly answered the question that I asked.  To answer your last question, yes, I have considered some manufactured products.  The highest efficiency that I've seen thus far is ~40-45% efficient--which is the reason for my question (i.e. to see if there is a better way of converting solar energy to heat energy that can be distributed as free supplemental heat.

Comment: Are there better ways? Of course. Can you manufacture aerogels and multi-layer interference filters? If you can, we can have a discussion about that... but if you are limited to materials from home depot (and let's be honest, you are), then you will have to replace efficiency by collection area.

Comment: @CuriousOne - That (i.e. replace efficiency with greater collection area) was understood from the start.  The question is essentially, what is the best common (relatively inexpensive) material that can be used in such a heat converter.  I offered 2 possibilities (a bk liner at the bottom of the box (i.e. probably a bk thermo-plastic liner) or bk painted AL & then I asked for other alternatives.  I even provided you with temp measurements for 3 materials in the hope that that would help, but that didn't move you in the intended direction, unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33873/discussion-between-curiousone-and-diyser).

Comment: I answered that very question in my first post: roofing materials. They are cheap and they can withstand the environmental conditions. I also said that I would avoid polymers. If you would like to talk in more detail, let's go to chat with this.

Comment: @CuriousOne - I initiated the chat room & messaged you there, but got no response from you.